# Can I put Hens and Chicks in the soil for cactus?

Tags: plant-care

I have some soil for cactus and I was wandering if it is ok to plant Hens and Chicks in this type of soil?

I have read aboout pH for the Hens and Chicks and it says it should be more than 7pH, and soil for Cactus has about 6, can it be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I did this two years ago and the plants are very happy and growing well. It's also suited for propagation by leaves.